# How to define login/signup and main controller workflow?

Tags: ios, ruby, rubymotion

I have a basic app with login/signup screen and main controller which is shown once the user has been logged in. Additionally, when the app is opened via a URL I want to show a modal controller.

I've tried several patterns on how to do this and have settled on the pattern below. It works, however, I feel there should be a better way to do this than what I am doing below. Problem with the below is that it doesn't open the modal controller when the app is opened via a URL

Here is what I am doing

```
class AppDelegate
  attr_reader :window
  include AFNetworkingClient

  def application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions)
    @window = UIWindow.alloc.initWithFrame(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds)
    if AppHelper.user_set?
      initAFNetworkingClient
      Color.fetch(AFMotion::Client) do |data|
        main_controller = ColorController.alloc.initWithData(data)
        @window.rootViewController = UINavigationController.alloc.initWithRootViewController(main_controller)
      end
    else
      main_controller = WelcomeController.alloc.initWithNibName(nil, bundle: nil)
      @window.rootViewController = UINavigationController.alloc.initWithRootViewController(main_controller)
    end
    @window.makeKeyAndVisible
    true
  end

  # This doesn't show the modal controller for some reason
  def application(application, openURL:url, sourceApplication:sourceApp, annotation:annotation)
    Color.fetch(AFMotion::Client) do |data|
      main_controller = ColorController.alloc.initWithData(data)
      ctlr = UINavigationController.alloc.initWithRootViewController(self.add_color_controller)
      ctlr.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical
      ctlr.delegate = self
      self.presentViewController(ctlr, animated:true, completion:nil)
    end
  end
  def add_color_controller
    @add_color_controller ||= MyModalController.new.tap do |ctlr|
        ctlr.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.alloc.initWithBarButtonSystemItem(
            UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel,
            target: self,
            action: :cancel)

        ctlr.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.alloc.initWithBarButtonSystemItem(
            UIBarButtonSystemItemDone,
            target: self,
            action: :done)

        ctlr.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = false
    end
  end

  def cancel
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil)
  end
end
```

*part of WelcomeController*

```
class WelcomeController < UIViewController
  include AFNetworkingClient
  def viewDidLoad
    super

    rmq.stylesheet = WelcomeControllerStylesheet
    rmq(self.view).apply_style :root_view

    display_login unless AppHelper.user_set?

  end
  def display_login
    @login = LoginController.alloc.init
    @login.delegate = self
    self.presentViewController(@login, animated:false, completion:nil)
  end
....
end
```

**Question**

- Is there a better way to manage the workflow I mentioned above?
- How can I fix the above code so that when I open the app with the url it doesn't throw error: `Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch`

Answer (score 0):

The thing that is missing is a controller that displays while `Color.fetch` is running.  So the method returns and `@window.rootViewController` hasn't been set to anything, until the block inside Color.fetch is called.  That's also why `presentViewController(..)` is having trouble - there's no controller to do the presenting!

So the first iteration would be to have a "loading" view controller.  That's not a *great* user experience, though... next I would modify the ColorController to store the last result of `Color.fetch` and display that, then when new data comes in update the UI.  A bit more work, but a better UX, I think.  And when there is no cached data it can have its own 'loading' screen, or it can present the LoadingViewController as a modal, something like that.

This would also involve moving the `Color.fetch` code OUT of the `AppDelegate`, which I strongly urge anyway (separation of concerns).  I think controllers should be responsible for loading their own data.